# Could a bunch of rocks form a center of gravity and orbit around it?

Tags: microgravity, modified-gravity

Essentially, 2 earth sized planets whacked each other, shattered and the collective gravity caused them to orbit around a semi-central area. The rocks range from boulder sized, to 30km long at the widest. Could the gravity sustain the rocks, or would there have to be some magic involved?

Comment: Don't you think two planets-worth of rubble is a lot different from "a bunch of rocks"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have described a planetary disc, which is the preliminary step for the formation of a planet.

Gravity will keep the fragment orbiting around the center of mass, but mutual interactions will dissipate part of their momentum causing their collapse and coalescence.

It happened also when [Theia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theia_(planet)) impacted Earth, leading to the formation of our Moon.

Comment: This scenario happens in the scifi novel Seveneves: the moon is whacked into 7 big pieces which continue to orbit the Earth (more or less) as a swirling grinding group around their gravitational center.